# React Native : how to get the selected checkboxes?

Tags: react-native

I have a checkbox list and I wanted to check which checkbox is selected after clicking the button

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Code complete

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Checkbox from 'react-native-custom-checkbox';

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checked: false,
        check:[]
    };
}

_myFunction(value,name,checked){
    console.log("Log:  "+value,checked);
};

clickButton(){

}

render() {

   let checkboxes = [];

   for(let i=0; i < 5;i++){
       checkboxes.push(
           <View>
           <Checkbox

           name='checkbox2'
           checked={false}
           size={30}
           style={{backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2', color:'blue', borderRadius: 5}}
           onChange={(name, checked) => this._myFunction(name,i, checked)}/>
           </View>
               );
   }

   return (
       <View>
           <Button onPress={()=>this.clickButton()}></Button>
           {checkboxes}

       </View>
    );

}

}
```